# Google analytics, can historical data be corrected? (after changing filter)

Tags: google-analytics

I have a view where a filter have been set up incorrectly in the past, leading to the URL's displaying with a forward slash in the beginning.

After fixing this, the URL's display correctly, but only for present and future data. Is there any way I can correct the historical data or is it not possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Once data is in GA, that's it.